# Output of a Java Loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hi all this is for a college assignment but I can't figure out how to this. The code is supposed to reverse a number. What I need to do is take the value of a variable after each loop iteration and add it as a string to another variable. At the moment it will only work if I output it the console what I would like is if I could output it to the Message Box. Below is my code.

```
         while (inputInt > 0){ //expression
            sum = inputInt % 10; //getting the modulas
            inputInt = inputInt / 10; //removing the last digit 
            sumStr = Integer.toString(sum); //converting to a string
            System.out.print(sumStr); //output to console
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sumStr, "Number Reverser", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); //displaying the output message box
```

The console is showing the correct result `4321` while the message box is only showing the last digit completed in the loop.

Comment: Try sumStr += Integer. toString(sum)

Comment: That's because sumStr is only one digit at a time. Hence your multiple prints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sumStr is being reset everytime you use the `=` sign.
For the message box, you need to append to the string not reset.

So you should do the following instead:

```
sumStr += Integer.toString(sum); //converting to a string
System.out.print(sum); //output to console
```

Comment: @MichaelOMeara If my answer helped you, can you please accept it as answer by clicking on the tick left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `sumStr += Integer.toString(sum);`Because you should add each digit right of the sumStr. `sumStr = Integer.toString(sum);` will assign last digit to "sumStr". And be sure that you define sumStr as `sumStr = "";` before the while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will also reverse the given number (without using a loop)

```
StringBuilder string1 = new StringBuilder(Integer.valueOf(inputInt).toString());
System.out.print(string1.reverse().toString()); //can use this value for message box as well
```

Comment: Super Thanks I think for the purpose of the exercise I have to use the loop but other than that Thank you probably use your method in the future :)